# Display curl result on phtml

Tags: magento2, curl

I created a custom module to fetch data from an external API and I would like to display it on the frontend.

I put my curl function in Helper\Data.php - Is it the best place to put it?

I called Helper\Data in my Block\Display.php but in the templates\display.phtml. It will show as blank.

Thank you in advance.

Block File:- **Block\Display.php**

```
  <?php

namespace NzPost\AddressFinder\Block;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \NzPost\AddressFinder\Helper\Data
     */
    private $helperData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \NzPost\AddressFinder\Helper\Data $helperData
    )
    {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        $client_id = $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('client_id');
        $client_secret = $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('client_secret');
        $result = $this->helperData->getCurl($client_id, $client_secret);
        return __($result);
    }
}
```

Template File:-**display.phtml**

```
    <?php
echo $this->sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code to show curl result on the template file.

**Block Code**

```
<?php

namespace NzPost\AddressFinder\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use NzPost\AddressFinder\Helper\Data;

/**
 * Class Display
 */
class Display extends Template
{

    /**
     * @var \NzPost\AddressFinder\Helper\Data
     */
    private $helperData;

    /**
     * Display constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $helperData,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }

    /**
     * @return Array
     */
    public function sayHello()
    {
        $client_id = $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('client_id');
        $client_secret = $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('client_secret');
        $result = $this->helperData->getCurl($client_id, $client_secret);

        return $result;
    }


}
```

**Template Code**

```
$CurlData = $block->sayHello();
var_dump($CurlData);
```

Comment: Hi @Devidas, I have tried this as well. But nothing shows up. If I add anything in the __construct(context $context, abc $abc) the phtml page will always show blank.

Comment: Hey, @TonyLe please check my block code I have updated.